# grails server push

Tags: grails, comet, server-push, atmosphere

I've been evaluating grails server push technologies, and I keep coming across the [grails atmosphere plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/atmosphere), but it doesn't seem like it is actively being developed. I've also seen the [grails events push plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/events-push). Is there a standard plugin that is being used for server push in grails? Is it one of these or another one all together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Grails events push plugin is the recommended one.

(I am the creator of Atmosphere).